# right way to use simple imputer?

Tags: python, data-science, imputation

I have a test- and a train-dataset with nan-values. I would like to use simple imputer in order to deal with them using the following code.

```
#numerical values
imp= SImp(strategy= 'median') #or 'mean', 'median', 'most_frequent' 
my_df.loc[:, num_cols_nan]= imp.fit_transform(def_df.loc[:, num_cols_nan])

#categorical values
imp= SImp(strategy= 'most_frequent')
my_df.loc[:, cat_cols_nan]= imp.fit_transform(def_df.loc[:, cat_cols_nan])`
```

My idea was to use median and `most_frequent` to fill in the NaNs.

However, browsing the web I find to different information on how to use the imputer:

- use fit_transform for the train data-set and transform for the test-set in order to perform the replacement based on the distribution on the train set.
- use fit_transform for train and test-set in order to perform the replacement based on the distribution of each set separately.

Just to clarify version 1. seems to be the most frequent case but since I'm a total beginner I'm kind of confused here.

So my question is which one is the "right" version to use?

Comment: The option `use fit_transform for the train data-set and transform for the test-set in order to perform the replacement based on the distribution on the train set.` will lead to data leakage because the test set will be "contaminated" with the train set

Comment: What is your question? The post here seems to lack one.

Comment: @TylerH: You are right sorry. I just wanted to know which version is the "correct" one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches that you mentioned are valid and can be used for imputing missing values in both train and test sets. The difference lies in the way the imputer is trained and applied to the data.

Approach 1: fit_transform on train set and transform on test set

In this approach, you fit the imputer on the train set using fit_transform, which learns the parameters (e.g. mean, median, most frequent) of the imputation model based on the distribution of the training data. Then, you use transform on the test set to impute missing values in the test set using the same learned parameters. This approach ensures that the test set is imputed based on the distribution of the training data, which is the goal in most cases.

Approach 2: fit_transform on train set and test set separately

In this approach, you fit the imputer separately on both the train and test sets using fit_transform. This means that the imputation parameters will be learned separately based on the distribution of each set, which may lead to different imputation results between the two sets. This approach is less common and is generally not recommended because it may lead to overfitting to the test set.

In general, it is recommended to use Approach 1 for imputing missing values in both the train and test sets. This ensures that the imputation is done based on the distribution of the training data, which is what we want to learn from. Additionally, it ensures that the same imputation model is used for both the train and test sets, which is important for ensuring consistency in the modeling process.

Comment: No I think option 2 is the only correct one as option 1 leads to data leakage https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/

Comment: thanks for bringing this to my attention
approach one may lead to data leakage.

Answer (score -1):

Option 2 is the correct one as option 1 leads to [data leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%20and,model.%5B1%5D)

From Wikipedia:

> In statistics and machine learning, leakage (also known as data
> leakage or target leakage) is the use of information in the model
> training process which would not be expected to be available at
> prediction time, causing the predictive scores (metrics) to
> overestimate the model's utility when run in a production
> environment.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%20and,model.%5B1%5D)
>
> Leakage is often subtle and indirect, making it hard to detect and
> eliminate. Leakage can cause a statistician or modeler to select a
> suboptimal model, which could be outperformed by a leakage-free
> model.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%20and,model.%5B1%5D)

If you modify the test data with information taken from the train data, then the test data will contain information taken from the train data, so it will not be completely independent as it should and the quality of the your evaluation will suffer from this, as the results will appear better than they are.